# Why my try catch block won't execute ? - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, next.js

I have a register modal which has 3 step.

Fill up the info, getActivate Code and Success Message.

I Want when user filled to inputs and clicked the submit button if there is no error move to next Step
but if there is error then `React Toastify` will show the message.

My problem is why `try catch` block in `MyComponent` dosen't work ?

P.S: I'm using `Formik` and `Yup`

httpService

```js
const handleExpectedError = (response: any) => {
  if (response?.status >= 400 && response?.status < 500) {
    const errors = response?.data?.errors;
    const errPropertyName: string[] = Object.keys(errors);
    toast.error(errors?.[errPropertyName?.[0]]?.[0]);
  }
};

export const handleRegister = async (user: User): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    await axios.post(`${config.apiEndPoint}/auth/register`, user, header);
  } catch ({ response }) {
    handleExpectedError(response);
  }
};
```

MyComponent

```js
  const [step, setStep] = useState(1);
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      email: "",
      phoneNumber: "",
      password: "",
    },
    onSubmit: (value) => {
      if (terms) {
        handleNextStep(value);
      }
    },
    validationSchema: registerSchema,
  });
  // Event Handler 
  // Value below is a referance to Formik object 
  const handleNextStep = async (value: any) => {
    if (step === 1) {
      try {
        await handleRegister(value);
        setStep(step + 1);
        await handeGetActivateCode({ email: value.email });
      } catch (error) {
        setStep(1);
      }
    }
    if (step !== 1) return setStep(step - 1);
  };
```

Comment: What do you mean by `try/catch` doesn't work, Do you mean that the `axios` request fail, and doesn't catch the error?

Comment: @Mina try/catch block works fine in ```httpService``` but in ```MyComponent``` dosen't work. the request fails but catch block won't execute

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In httpService file, you have used try-catch. In that catch you are trying to get the error in the **curly braces**, instead of doing like that if you do the following thing. then the catch block will work fine

```
export const handleRegister = async (user: User): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    await axios.post(`${config.apiEndPoint}/auth/register`, user, header);
  } catch (response) {
    handleExpectedError(response);
  }
};
```